# How to access module from rake file

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm trying to expose variables used in my rake task to its test file.

`app/lib/tasks/my_rake.rake`

```
module MyRake
  VAR = 'foo'
end

task :my_rake do
   # use VAR
end
```

`spec/lib/tasks/my_rake_spec.rb`

```
describe 'my_rake' do
  include MyRake
  # use VAR
end
```

but when I run `my_rake_spec.rb`, I get `NameError: uninitialized constant MyRake`

Answer (score 0):

found this worked:

```
describe 'my_rake' do
  MyRake::VAR
end
```